# How to redirect after saving inside each with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to `rails` and I have doubts when it comes to redirecting after saving a mass process.

```
  def massive_create_progress
    @values = params[:progress].try(:[], :form_data) || {}
    @procedures = Procedure.where(flow_id: @current_flow, responsible_id: current_user)
    @procedures.each do |procedure|
      @progress = Progress.new(step: @step, responsible: current_user, form_data: @values, edited_progress: @edited_progress)
      if @progress.save!
        procedure.association_procedures.create!(associable: @progress.procedure)
      else
        @progress.errors.add(:base, "As informações não atendem as regras estabelecidas.") if @progress.errors.empty?
      end
    end
  end
```

Above is my `controller`, where I want to redirect

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: add a redirect_to inside the if and the else of @progress.save!

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Comment: Just before the end of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to make this redirect

```
  def massive_create_progress
    error = false
    @values = params[:progress].try(:[], :form_data) || {}
    @procedures = Procedure.where(flow_id: @current_flow, responsible_id: current_user)
    @procedures.each do |procedure|
      @progress = Progress.new(step: @step, responsible: current_user, form_data: @values, edited_progress: @edited_progress)
      if @progress.save!
        procedure.association_procedures.create!(associable: @progress.procedure)
      else
        errors = true if @progress.errors
      end
    end
  end
```